# doClick() and SetText() in Jpanel from Jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I'm new in Java programming.
I developed a GUI in Netbeans (unfortunately using drag and drop).

I created a JFrame and two JPanel (using CardLayout).

**JFrame:**

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    int key=evt.getKeyCode();

    switch (key) {

            case 105: 
                UpdatePanel update=new UpdatePanel(105);
                break;

            case 97:
                CardLayout showPanel = (CardLayout) panelCard.getLayout();
                showPanel.show(panelCard, "Incasso");
                break;

            case 99:
                showPanel = (CardLayout) panelCard.getLayout();
                showPanel.show(panelCard, "Selezione");
                break;
```

So when I press keycode 99, it shows the panelCard `"Selezione"`, and with keycode 97, panelCard `"Incasso"`

This works properly.

With keycode 105 it calls the class `UpdatePanel`.

```
public class UpdatePanel {
  public UpdatePanel(int key){
    switch (key) {
        case 105:
            Selezione variabile= new Selezione();

            variabile.fascia.setText("io");

            break;
    }
}
```

The scope of this class is to update the component inside the panels.
In this sample I try to update the text field `"fascia"` that is a component inside the panel `"Selezione"`.

I compiled the files without errors. When I press the button (code 105) the class `UpdatePanel` is instantiated successfully, but the fieldText `"fascia"` is not updated in the panel.

What am I doing wrong ?

I tried to some modifications, but most of the code was made by the drag and drop wizard, so I do not have direct access.

Comment: You're using a new Selezione() object that is accessible only in the scope of the switch case. Why not using the initial Selezione object?

Comment: When I figured out how to solve this problem, in the class UpdatePanel , I must also have to add doClick () to simulate the pressure of the buttons present in the Panels

Comment: Sorry Yassin, i do not understand your answer ,, the fieldtext fascia is public in the class Selezione (that contain the jpanel)

Comment: If you want to use the Selezione() object outside of the switch case, it must be declared outside of the switch.

Comment: Don't run if the compiler has errors. Paste the errors here  so people can explain how to fix them.

Comment: Hi Yassin ok i understand that .. but this is not my problem , for example if i remove the switch case still do not update the textfield in the panel  WillShackleford no errors when i compile

Comment: This has nothing to do with public vs private (and the fields should **all** be private by the way), but rather you're creating objects that are local to your control structures and methods, and that have little to do with the displayed objects. You really need to create and post your [mcve] for us to be able to help you well. This is not a complete code dump but rather a small program that runs and that demonstrates your problem for us. Read the link.

Comment: *"doClick() and SetText() in Jpanel from Jframe"* As an aside, that title suggests the code `extends JFrame` and `extends JPanel` where it really shouldn't extend either.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think I found the problem.
When I used the CardLayout, the compiler created two other objects selezione1 adn incasso1 (private).

I solved it by changing selezione1 and incasso1 in public and
changing Selezione.fascia.setText ("io"); with selezione1.fascia.setText("io"); Now work .. thanks to all .. now i like to post my code to know how make it better, but the problem the drag and drop .. this make many line of code so i need time to learn ho to make a gui by code before post 200 line of code :(

Comment: Yes Andrew i will .. as soon as I get rid of the many lines of code of the drug and drop wizard .. I create a minimal code and i post . Yes is extends Jframe and Jpanels made by the drag and drop wizard

Comment: Other problems: you're using a KeyListener, something that usually should be avoided with Swing GUI's, and you're using "magic" numbers, hard-coded numbers that are hard for folks looking at your code to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`UpdatePanel` does not look like a good class name. It is better good for a method name, to say `doSomething`. If you are intending to write a class responsible for updating panel, better name it as `PanelUpdater`.

You could have written the case `105` as

```
case 105: 
       fascia.setText("io");
       break;
```

**Or** if you needed to do this with a class, say `PanelUpdater`,

```
public class PanelUpdater {
  public PanelUpdater (int key, JTextField field){
    switch (key) {
        case 105:
            field.setText("io");
            break;
    }
}
```

and

```
case 105: 
                PanelUpdater panelUpdater = new PanelUpdater (105, fascia);
                break;
```

But I do not recommend this approach of creating an `Object` unnecessarily.